# What should I put on a Nexus 7 to make it safer for my children?

Tags: android, security, parental-control, children

I wish to encourage my children (aged 12 & 10) to use their Nexus 7 tablet (Android KitKat) as widely as possible.  However, I would prefer them not to misuse the privilege.  I wish to block access to:

- Pornography
- Buying random stuff on my credit card
- Antisocial websites (from some public blacklist, manually entered or both)

I wish to allow:

- Contact with friends
- Access to child-friendly web sites
- Games (that I have checked)

In case it affects your answer, the tablet has WiFi access to the internet but it is not a phone and will have no cellular access.

Free, one-off payment and subscription formats would all be acceptable suggestions.

Comment: Apps covering at least your keypoints (including blacklists etc) mostly come with a monthly subscription fee. Apart from those, I never encountered a fitting "all-in-one package". Would those apps be acceptable? Also, as a side-effect, they are quite permission-hungry, and not always explain what they use which permission for. To give you an example, please take a look at [NQ Family Guardian](http://www.appbrain.com/app/nq-family-guardian/com.nq.familyguardian).

Comment: One more point. You've probably to decide between using multiple apps covering parts, or one big thing covering all *and more* (usually tracking stuff, geo-fencing, remote "control", ...). And at least the latter have the "permission catalog" I've mentioned. I'm afraid, you'll have to live with one or the other (I dug into that a while ago, see my lists [here](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/445686/) and [here](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/435325/); don't mind the German, just check app names and their links ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Parentsaround Parental Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pdlp.android.app) should do the trick for you

> Parental Control for Android which includes safe browser, apps control and time management.
>
> This application is a parental control for android phones and tablets, which allows to :
>
> - Define applications accessible by the child during his schedule
> - Set up rescue applications : they will be always accessible (like the phone application)
> - Define schedules for the use of differents devices
> - Limit the time of use per day and per week
> - Protect your children against inappropriate content thanks to several levels of Internet filtering a secure browser
> - Secure their navigation with the safe browser of parentsaround.com

It also allows you to control the device from any computer or smartphone, which allows you to view the applications that your children are using, the websites they have visited and change the allowed/disallowed apps on-the-fly.

It costs $39 a year (or $4 a month) and it comes with a free 30 day trial. You can get a subscription [here](http://www.parentsaround.com/informations-and-price.html)

Answer (score 4):

**[NQ Family Guardian](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.nq.familyguardian)** might be a candidate:

- *Blocking access to specific websites:* It offers a Web Filter to block inappropriate websites.
- *Deny Buying random stuff on my credit card:* It has an App Filter, so you can decide which apps should be used. Exclude e.g. *Playstore* so they cannot buy apps.
- *Allow Contact with friends:* The included contact filter can be setup to block certain numbers. As I didn't use the app myself, I cannot say if a white-list (i.e. block all but those you explicitly permit) is possible as well. But this part seems less important in context of a WiFi only tablet :)
- *Allow access to Games (that I have checked):* See above: don't block them :)

Additionally, there are more features like a scheduler (limit the times your kids can use the device or certain apps), and more.

The app comes with a 30d trial. After that, a monthly subscription fee of USD 5 applies.

[image: Family Guardian: Menu] [image: Monitors] [image: Filters]
<sup>Selected Screenshots (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

**Note:** The app requests a lot of permissions. I cannot say which ones are needed for what. Considered the features the app offers, they sound reasonable, though.

Comment: Most parental control apps have to request to be a device administrator so that the app can block other apps and global internet access. Also looking at the permissions and the features, this seems to be more like a phone monitor then a tablet monitor. Thus is why is requests permissions to grab the contacts and SMS messages. Still a good app either way, so nothing really to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a few things, most of which are free

1. Set up [content filtering on google play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1075738?hl=en). You can also password protect app purchases. You *want* to do this in addition to anything else. I'd also suggest having a seperate account for the nexus 7, and link that to yours - that way you'd have a second layer of protection
2. [lock down](http://www.google.com.sg/goodtoknow/familysafety/tools/) search and youtube with their respective safety modes
3. Depending on how much control you want you can use a proxy server for content filtering. By long pressing a network, selecting "modify network" and "show advanced options", you can select a proxy server. While its not completely impossible to disable, it would prevent accidentally accessing things they shouldn't. I've used privoxy in the past, and there seem to be [content filters available for it](http://papy.no.sapo.pt/). Parental content proxies may be a question for the future ;).

Comment: I would note that strictly speaking, very little of this is an actual software recommendation. This wouldn't fit into a comment, and its fairly useful. I do believe 4.3 and 4.4 has even better in build settings, but I have no way to check at the moment [pc advisor](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/google-android/3461359/parental-control-on-android/) has a nice article on it